# Why an ajax call doesn't give .is_ajax()=True?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-views

My template.html:

```
...
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="save_post(event, 'publish')">Publish</button>
...
```

My javascript.js:

```
function save_post(event, action) {
  event.preventDefault();#new line
  var tag_string=document.getElementById('id_tags').value;
  if (action=='publish' || action=='draft') {
    var url_post='/blog/post/new/'
  } else {
    var url_post='/blog/post_edit/'
  };

  $.ajax({type: 'POST',
    url: url_post,
    data: {
      tagstring: tag_string,
      action: action
    },
    success: function (lista) {
        //code
    }
  });
};
```

My views.py:

```
@staff_member_required
def post_new(request):
    context_dict=[]
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.is_ajax():
            #code
        ...

    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', context_dict)
```

My `url.py`:

```
app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('post/new/', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/edit/', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
    ...
```

My views is called by the url (browser), then the button call a javascript function and it call (with ajax) again the same view, this time with `request.method = "POST"` and this works, but `request.is_ajax()` gives `False`.

For call post_edit (probabily) I need the id of the post. Where can I get it?
Should I pass it to save_post() from the template?

Edit: ignore these lines below

Also should I use `preventDefault()` somewhere?

Thank you

Edit: now I use `preventDefault()` but it gives this error:

```
Not Found: /blog/post_new/
[26/Jan/2018 19:07:20] "POST /blog/post_new/ HTTP/1.1" 404 10871
```

and ajax dosn't call the view. Edit: I solved this problem, but I continue tomorrow :)

Comment: If you don't use `preventDefault`, then the browser will still submit the form (the default action) once the callback has finished. My guess is that it's this request for which `request.is_ajax()` returns `False`.

Comment: in save_post event.preventDefault(); gives error: event is not defined. I tried save_post(event, publish) but doesn't work

Comment: because you did not pass in the event

Comment: Ok, I pass the event but now it say: Not Found: /blog/post_new/ and the view isn't called...

Comment: How can we help with a `Not Found` errror, if you haven’t shown your url patterns?

Comment: Sorry, until now it was working so I didn't think it could be the url. Ok, maybe I get it, I'm using the name, not the path

Comment: You should post to the actual url, e.g. `/post/new/`, or use the url tag to reverse e.g. `{% url 'blog:post_new' %}`.

Answer (score -2):

**Your Ajax code some problems and view is correct**

**I have attached my Code attached Image  and code**

```
$.ajax({
                type : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
                url  : 'myajaxview', // the url where we want to POST
                data :{
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}',
                    'text': text,
                    'search': search,
                    'email': email,
                    'url': url,
                    'telephone': telephone,
                    'password': password,
                    'number': number,
                },
                dataType : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                encode   : true
            })
```

[image]

Comment: what is your problem about this answer

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but the answer would be better if you explained what was wrong and what you fixed. Including the code is enough, you don’t need the screenshot.

Comment: Not mine the downvote but I can't make work your code for me. But I'm still working on it

Comment: you need to add form csrf token in your data and method dataType, encode missed for that reason i added code

Comment: for more reference my github project https://github.com/gowthamand/django-crud-ajax-login-register-fileupload/blob/master/crud/templates/crud/signup.html

Comment: I am the downvote and surprised it does not have more. No explanation, just code and there is really no reason why anyone would need to do what you put in your answer.

Comment: @epascarello i told problem and i gave example code then what else can do

Comment: It would be better to edit the answer and add the explanation there, rather than adding it in the comments. User's want to see a complete answer here on Stack Overflow, they'd rather not have to click through to another site.

Comment: @Alasdair i  told problem and i gave example code then what else can do